# Apache mod_proxy redirect url with parameters

Tags: apache, url, parameters, mod-proxy

I want to redirect requests like this `http://myproxy.com/site:5000/response-headers/action?Content-Length=30` to `http://site:5000/response-headers/action?Content-Length=30` . 
I use mod_proxy and my config for apache:

```
LoadModule proxy_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule proxy_http_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_proxy_http.so
LoadModule proxy_html_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_proxy_html.so
        ProxyRequests Off
        ProxyPreserveHost On
         <proxy *>
         Order deny,allow
         Allow from all
         </proxy>

ProxyPass /site:5000/response-headers/action?Content-Length=30  http://site:5000/response-headers/action?Content-Length=30 
ProxyPassReverse /site:5000/response-headers/action?Content-Length=30  http://site:5000/response-headers/action?Content-Length=30
```

When i try to request `http://myproxy.com/site:5000/response-headers/action?Content-Length=30` i see this error:

```
Proxy Error

The proxy server received an invalid response from an upstream server.
The proxy server could not handle the request GET /site:5000/response-headers/action.

Reason: DNS lookup failure for: response-headers
```

In apache log:

```
[error] [client 10.1.76.95] proxy: DNS lookup failure for: response-headers returned by /site:5000/response-headers/action
[debug] proxy_util.c(2029): proxy: HTTP: has released connection for (*)
[debug] mod_deflate.c(615): [client 10.1.76.95] Zlib: Compressed 610 to 366 : URL /site:5000/response-headers/action
```

For example, if i setting redirect from `http://myproxy.com/site.com` to `http://site.com` it's work fine.

How i must setting apache and mod_proxy to solve my problem?

Many thanks.